# System.Windows.Forms.TreeView Checkbox Selection

Tags: c#

I am using `System.Windows.Forms.TreeView` control. I have code that is fired via the `OnAfterCheck` method on the `AfterCheck` event for check all the child nodes.

Its working fine when I single click, but whenever I double click on the checkbox, the parent check box and all the child nodes become unchecked.

Is there any way to disable this behavior on the double-click of a checkbox, or handle the double-click checkbox event another way?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `DoubleClick` Event. Pass a blank method to the `OnDoubleClick` method of the `TreeView` class. That way, nothing will happen when the box is double-clicked, or you can change it so that something does happen. See the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.ondoubleclick.aspx) for more information.